# PHP: Change array1 value based on array2 value

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have 2 arrays. Sometimes a key/value from array1 may equals to key/value of array2. If that is true, change 'status' from the specific key/value from array2, to a new value. Does that make sense?

Here is where I am at:

```
foreach($array1 as $i=>$x){
          foreach($array2 as $k=>$y){
            if($x['url'] == $y['url']){

              // Up to here works

              foreach($i as &$value) {
                $value['status'] = 'new value';
            }

              break;
            }
          }
        }
```

This are my arrays:

```
array(1) { 
    [0]=> array(1) {
        ["url"]=> string(104) "aHR0cDovL3lvdXR1YmUuY29t"
        ["date"]=> string(19) "2014-01-06 21:44:39"
        ["status"]=> string(1) "0"
     }

    [1]=> array(1) { 
        ["url"]=> string(28) "d3d3LnR3aXR0ZXIuY29t"
        ["date"]=> string(19) "2014-01-06 14:28:32"
        ["status"]=> string(1) "0"
     }
 }
```

and array2:

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> array(2) {
        ["url"]=> string(104) "aHR0cDovL3lvdXR1YmUuY29t"
        ["date"]=> string(19) "2014-01-06 21:44:39" 
     }

    [1]=> array(2) { 
        ["url"]=> string(28) "aHR0cDovL3d3dy5nb29nbGUuY29t"
        ["date"]=> string(19) "2014-01-06 14:28:32"
     }
 }
```

Up to the comment it works. From there after, how can I change that specific key/value to a new value? My current example changes all key 'status' to 'new value'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to loop again through `array1` just change the key of it

```
$array1[$i]['status'] = 'new value';
```

Comment: Although var_dump($x['status']); posts as: string(1) "0", $x['status'] = 'new value'; doesnt change anything

Comment: I updated my answer, does that makes more sense to you?

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
<?php
    $array1 = array(
        array(
            "url"   =>  "aHR0cDovL3lvdXR1YmUuY29t",
            "date"  =>  "2014-01-06 21:44:39",
            "status"    =>  "0"
            )
        );
    $array2 = array(
        array(
            "url"   =>  "aHR0cDovL3lvdXR1YmUuY29t",
            "date"  =>  "2014-01-06 21:44:39",
            )
        );

    array_walk($array2, function($arr2) use (&$array1)
    {
        foreach($array1 as &$arr1)
        {
            if($arr2['url'] == $arr1['url'])
                $arr1['status'] = "something";
        }
    });

    print_r($array1);
```

**Output**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [url] => aHR0cDovL3lvdXR1YmUuY29t
            [date] => 2014-01-06 21:44:39
            [status] => something
        )
)
```

Comment: @jQuerybeast sorry I misunderstood at first. check the update.

Comment: Thank you. I will be using your method since I can avoid all those foreach methods for performance issues.